# Media Plugin getCurrentPosition repeated call stops after some time

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I just startet to use the Media plugin on iOS.

I recognized that when playing a sound file and retrieving the current position repeatedly with setInterval() it only works when the interval is high enough. If I set the interval to 50ms it stops calling after around 20s. If I set it to 20ms it even stops earlier.

It wouldn't be so bad when working with the getCurrentPosition method, but I changed the plugin to get the volume level of an audio file or the microphone and there I want to retrieve the value around every 50ms, but the same happens here.

The code I tested it with, written in CoffeeScript:

```
@media = new Media("asd.wav",
    () -> console.log "Media success"
    (err) -> console.log "Media error " + err
 );

 @media.play()

_media = @media
setInterval(
    () ->
        _media.getCurrentPosition(
            (value) ->
                console.log value
            (e) ->  console.log "Error:" + e
        )
    , 50)
```

Thanks for suggestions and help. 
Patrick

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?